# Platform to run jupyter notebooks on schedule

Tags: automation, jupyter-notebook, cloud, scheduled-tasks

I am in search for a platform that will allow me to work on jupyter notebooks and  schedule them. I also need to be able upload/download files to this platform manually. The scripts are mainly for web scraping and data formatting so I do not need too much functionality.

I have been trying to use google cloud platform for this purpose but failed to build a working set up as it was too complicated for me. Also tried Azure but I find google cloud/microsoft have too many features that makes them very difficult to navigate for users like me which have simple use cases.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try a [Notebooker](https://github.com/man-group/notebooker) or [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury). Both are open-source web-based solutions for scheduling and sharing Jupyter Notebooks. The Mercury has an option to [download output files](https://mercury-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/output-files/).

You can also try online service with Notebooks like [NaaS](https://naas.ai), [Noteable](https://noteable.io), [DeepNote](https://deepnote.com) - they have scheduling capabilities.